# jQuery: Accessing a textarea's current text from a button's click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I'm writing a function to make an AJAX POST request on the click of an input button with jQuery. The button's click function is being defined in `$(document).ready()`. What I'm noticing is, when the button is clicked, the text pulled from the textarea is the default text it was populated with, and not whatever the user may have changed it to. Code snippet follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#add-note-button').click(function() {
    var note_data = {};
    note_data["notetext"] = $('#notetext').text();
    alert($('#notetext').text());
    note_data["author"] = 123;

    $.ajax( {
      type:'POST',
      url:'/myapp/post_note/1/',
      data:note_data,
      success: function(data){
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Later on in the HTML:

```
<textarea id="notetext">Add status update... </textarea>
<input id='add-note-button' type='submit' value="Save"/>
```

The `alert($('#notetext').text());` from the `click()` function above only ever shows "Add status update..." and not the text I am typing into the textarea.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$('#notetext').val();
```

instead of

```
$('#notetext').text();
```

The [`.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val) gets the current value of form elements.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Will accept as correct answer once SO's timer runs out.

Comment: sorry nnnnn I didn't see your answer is the same as mine, do you think I should delete mine since we say the same?

Comment: Well @Gnagno I generally delete my own answers if I realise they're duplicates, _unless_ I've said something important that the previous poster didn't mention or if I think I've explained the solution better than they did - in which case it might be argued that they're not duplicates, but sometimes it happens that several people post the same _code_ but provide different _explanations_ (or vice versa), so...

Comment: @nnnnn thank you for your reply, of course I dind't copy you, I just wanted to know about the netiquette here in stackoverflow, but I think now we are going OT, I deleted my post, bye :)